# ordered list doesn't increment in firefox 57

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have an issue in Firefox 57 with ordered lists in html.

The html is dynamically generated, but an example looks like this:

```
<ol>
  <li>ashdg</li>
  <li>ashdg</li>
  <li>ashdg</li>
</ol>
```

It has the following CSS

```
ol{
    margin-top: 0px !important;
    margin-bottom: 0px !important;
    list-style-type: decimal !important;
    list-style-position: inside !important;
}

p, ul, ol {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline;
}
```

The firefox output

[image: FireFox output]

Chrome output

[image]

Comment: JSFiddle for those that want to reproduce: https://jsfiddle.net/0b5zh6xf/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### 2021 Update

The bug, where `display: inline` causes a reset of the order in ordered lists seems to be fixed in current Firefox Versions! (Tested in Firefox 94, but it is likely that it was fixed way earlier).

### Original Answer

This is casued by `display: inline`, but **I don't know why** this resets the order of lists in Firefox. I would not say this is intuitive and expected, so **in my opinion**, it is a **bug**. If the `inline` property is not necessary, just remove the `ol` in your CSS. If it *is* necesary (because you want them to be in one line), there is a workaround using `float` instead of `display: inline`.

```css
ol{
    margin-top: 0px !important;
    margin-bottom: 0px !important;
    list-style-type: decimal !important;
    list-style-position: inside !important;
}

p, ul, /* ol <-- remove this, if not necessary */ {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline;
}

/* add this, if necessary */
ol li {
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<ol>
   <li>ashdg</li>
   <li>ashdg</li>
   <li>ashdg</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: I agree that it looks like a bug. However, I'd like to notice that setting `display:inline` to the list container without "inlinification" of the items (leaving them with their default `display:list-item` value, which basically means the same as `display:block`, but with an extra list marker box) looks quite pointless. It still results in the list breaking from the line and behaving like a block (the items end up being wrapped in the anonymous block box), and anonymous boxes often bring surpises.

Answer (score 2):

Just replace this::

```
p, ul, ol {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline;
}
```

by::

```
p, ul, ol {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add one new property with `-moz` prefix at any property? Like `moz-grid`, `-moz-appearance`.
You wouldn't naturally need this, but you can try.
Also check if there's another css code that changes your `ol` property (check for `-moz`, too).

---

It doesn't make sense, but looks like the `display:inline` will make it looks like "one-line-list", and `ol` in Firefox count the boxes from the lines.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "add one new property with the -moz prefix"? Add what property? Perhaps you could give some sample code to demonstrate what you mean...

Comment: As far as I know, `-moz-display` does not exist at all